# Accurately return dict to tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to create a set of `tuples` from various values in a `dict`. Using the example below, It works up until the `_10` `integer`. So anything above `_9` gets overwritten. e.g `_12` becomes `_2`.

```
time = [1]

d = ({  
    'A1_S' : [10],    
    'A2_S' : [20],                       
    'A3_S' : [30],    
    'A4_S' : [40],        
    'A5_S' : [50],    
    'A6_S' : [60],                       
    'A7_S' : [70],    
    'A8_S' : [80],                    
    'A9_S' : [90],    
    'A10_S' : [100],                       
    'A11_S' : [110],    
    'A12_S' : [120],
    'A13_S' : [130],    
    'A14_S' : [140],                       
    'A15_S' : [150],                        
    }) 

tuples = [((t, k.split('_')[0][0], int(k.split('_')[0][1]), k.split('_')[1]), v[i]) for k,v in d.items() for i,t in enumerate(time)]
```

Output:

```
[((1, 'A', 1, 'S'), 10), ((1, 'A', 2, 'S'), 20), ((1, 'A', 3, 'S'), 30), ((1, 'A', 4, 'S'), 40), ((1, 'A', 5, 'S'), 50), ((1, 'A', 6, 'S'), 60), ((1, 'A', 7, 'S'), 70), ((1, 'A', 8, 'S'), 80), ((1, 'A', 9, 'S'), 90), ((1, 'A', 1, 'S'), 100), ((1, 'A', 1, 'S'), 110), ((1, 'A', 1, 'S'), 120), ((1, 'A', 1, 'S'), 130), ((1, 'A', 1, 'S'), 140), ((1, 'A', 1, 'S'), 150)]
```

Intended Output:

```
[((1, 'A', 1, 'S'), 10), ((1, 'A', 2, 'S'), 20), ((1, 'A', 3, 'S'), 30), ((1, 'A', 4, 'S'), 40), ((1, 'A', 5, 'S'), 50), ((1, 'A', 6, 'S'), 60), ((1, 'A', 7, 'S'), 70), ((1, 'A', 8, 'S'), 80), ((1, 'A', 9, 'S'), 90), ((1, 'A', 10, 'S'), 100), ((1, 'A', 11, 'S'), 110), ((1, 'A', 12, 'S'), 120), ((1, 'A', 13, 'S'), 130), ((1, 'A', 14, 'S'), 140), ((1, 'A', 15, 'S'), 150)]
```

Comment: What should your output look like? Also, in your title you say 'df' but in the question you say dict. Assuming you want to use a dict but just want to double check

Comment: @G.Anderson, sorry, the question has been amended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int(k.split('_')[0][1]
```

You're only grabbing one character after the 'A' where you mean to be grabbing all the characters after 'A' until the '_'. You can use this instead to grab all the characters until the split:

```
int(k.split('_')[0][1:]
```

So the whole thing should be:

```
tuples = [((t, k.split('_')[0][0], int(k.split('_')[0][1:]), k.split('_')[1]), v[i]) for k,v in d.items() for i,t in enumerate(time)]
```